# How to get highlighting from interactive regex search in emac to remain highlight until deactivated?

Tags: search, emacs, highlighting

How to get highlighting from interactive regex search in emac to remain highlight until deactivated?  For instance, with the text provided and running M-C-s (Regexp I-Search) with input 'file' will highlight the 3 'file' words in the text below.

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.

Regexp I-Search %> file
```

But, once I start to edit the file the highlighting will disappear.  I'd like to keep the highlighting for a while -- until I run another command to turn it off.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `highlight-regexp` bound to <kbd>M-s h r</kbd>.  <kbd>M-s h u</kbd> unhighlights.

[highlight-symbol](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/) provides a nice wrapper around this.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the variable `lazy-highlight-cleanup` to `nil`, then the highlight remains until the next search:

```
(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)
```

Or, until you manually call <kbd>M-x lazy-highlight-cleanup</kbd>.